# phpmyAdmin urls return blank page

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded my php from 7.4 to 8.0 after that, I can log in to phpmyadmin and it shows all databases but after one second all databses disappear,and when I click on every tab it returns blank page like this one : (I work on ubuntu)
[image]

Comment: Check your browser console to confirm if you aren't receiving any errors.

Comment: Please share your PHPMyAdmin version number.

Comment: version : 4:5.1.4+dfsg1-1+focal1 @steven7mwesigwa 
and I did not find any error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded phpmyadmin to version 5

https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/

And now it works

Comment: This solution has worked for me.  updated phpmyadmin to version 5.2.0 and it works good with php8.0

Answer (score 1):

Before installing PHP 8.0. you need to remove the old version

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.4
(or)
sudo apt-get --purge remove php7.4
```

Or

Disable the old version and enable the new version,

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.0
```

Now check the PHP version,

```
php -v
```

Then restart the apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Otherwise, follow the URL

https://devanswers.co/how-to-upgrade-from-php-7-x-to-php-8-on-ubuntu-apache/